# Mysql store HTML code

Tags: mysql, database

If I want to store HTML code to a database, is better to add one row with big HTML code or more rows with smaller HTML code?

In my app, I can edit the code in both ways, so don't really need more rows, but maybe is faster or more effective having more rows and smaller HTMl code.

What is your opinion? Thanks you.

HTML Code Example:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <section data-type="component-text">
      content
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <section data-type="component-photo">
      content
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <section data-type="component-video">
    content
  </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code is generated by a plugin. This is only an example created by me.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you would be separating the rows?

Comment: Why you do not save your html code as file ?,i guess is better than more rows and text.

Comment: @JakubJudas I edited the post. I would add row by row.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I need to store logo,nav,footer, and body. I dont't really want to use files. I wante to use Sessions, because is only a temporary store.

Comment: I'd say that in this case, it will be more future proof to save each content in a separate place than to save the whole thing as html. This will make the content immune to any design changes etc.
As for whether to store it as one row with content_video, content_photo and content_text, or another table with content_type and content - I'd say the latter is more future proof too.

Comment: @JakubJudas I am making a websie builder and user can click to another page, so I want to save the content temporary until he publish all the content using Publish button.

Comment: Keeping it separate will still give you more flexibility and unless you expect serious traffic, the performance difference does not matter.

Comment: @JakubJudas it only a Bachelor project, so I want have any traffic :) Then i will save them row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer:* It depends on your querying needs.

**Efficient querying** is an extensive topic focused on design and algorithms.
It depends on the *size*, *type* and *structure* of the data you have.

If you just need to store all the HTML and get it back, you could simply store as much per block.

If you need specific lines of HTML per query then each block with the necessary content is a good idea!

I hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the with a plugin, so I can store all the HTML and then get it back. The HTML code is stored temporary. Because user can click to another page and I dont want to lose the content.

Comment: I see that the content you need is only : text, photo,video.
You can store that information only for the specific user say (use different columns) with SQL?
Are you using a framework? It makes it easier to just inject the information in the HTML that is there.
It would be a lot of wasted table space to store the entire HTML to describe the div's.

Comment: There are more components like youtube,googlemaps, but the code is more or less the same.

Comment: You don't want to store all the html, it is a little inefficient. I would store only the required information. Depending on the database you are using. If in this case SQL , you can create columns for the necessary types of content.. (can become a lot). If it was a JSON format database, MongoDB it would be pretty good, you could store all fields in a javascript type object. It seems efficient for your type of data. Check it out !

Comment: I am making a website builder and user can click to another page, so I want to save temporary the changes he made until he publish the content using Publish button. I've got 3 choices: making a temporary file, session, or database. I must save the HTML inside the section with content-type.

Comment: I saw that you wanted to store all the info in session, as you mentionned in a comment to a different user . I strongly do not recommend that, read a little more on storing data in session :).

Comment: It looks ugly to save so much HTML in sessions, so I chose to store it to a temporary table and delete the rows after publish.

Comment: Use a database, especially as you will begin to grow your website/scale your application, you will see that more data will be stored. It seems to be that if you have users, you will be needing to store user information as well...These are all database items! Hope this helps :). If this is a small app for something you can still use files, but I suggest you try out using databases, see how data is stored ,what is efficient. It is definitely a good learning experience!

Comment: Thanks. I will use the database. I have user and projects. For the moment Then i will save them row by row.